# Unable to change path of QSettings

Tags: c++, qt, qsettings

I use the `c:\windows\winf32.ini` to store software parameters, I can read it by doing this:

```
QSettings settings("c:/windows/winf32.ini", QSettings::IniFormat, Q_NULLPTR);
```

I can read the file with the absolute path but when I use `setValue()` and `sync()`, the file is not updated.
However, with relative path `"winf32.ini"` he write correctly the change but it is not in the `c:\windows\` path.
By default, with the `QSettings::IniFormat`, the folowing files are used:

1. FOLDERID_RoamingAppData\MySoft\Star Runner.ini
2. FOLDERID_RoamingAppData\MySoft.ini
3. FOLDERID_ProgramData\MySoft\Star Runner.ini
4. FOLDERID_ProgramData\MySoft.ini

So to change it, I have tried this:

```
QSettings::setPath(QSettings::IniFormat, QSettings::UserScope, "c:/windows");
QSettings::setPath(QSettings::IniFormat, QSettings::SystemScope, "c:/windows");
QSettings settings("winf32.ini", QSettings::IniFormat, Q_NULLPTR);
```

But `settings` is empty.
I use `setPath` before declare my `settings` variable because in the [QSettings doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#setPath), it says:

> Warning: This function doesn't affect existing QSettings objects.

I don't see what is the problem.

Comment: Be sure to have write permissions in C:\windows

Comment: @Fabio, Yes, I am administrator and when I call ```settings.isWritable();```, it's true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely a permissions issue. Your user may have administrative privileges but due to [UAC (User Account Control)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) you must explicitly grant those privileges to any new process, otherwise that process will be execute with a lower authorization level. For example, this is the reason why Windows asks you every time if you want to run certain software (such as installers) as administrator, even when your user *is* the administrator.

To check it, just open the File Explorer, go to the directory where your executable was compiled, right-click on the executable and choose "Run as administrator". Windows (actually, the UAC) will ask you to confirm the action. After it, check your INI file has been modified.

You can force your executable to ask for administrative privileges every time it runs by setting a linker flag:

- Visual Studio: go to project's properties, then *Linker* > *Manifest File* > *UAC Execution Level* and set it to `requireAdministrator`. (Do not forget to set it for all the configurations of your project).

  [image]
- Qt Creator (qmake): add `QMAKE_LFLAGS += /MANIFESTUAC:\"level=\'requireAdministrator\' uiAccess=\'false\'\"` to your .pro file.

---

For completeness of the answer, my tests were performed with the code below:

```
#include <QSettings>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  QSettings settings("c:/windows/winf32.ini", QSettings::IniFormat);

  settings.setValue("hello", "world");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have tried to change this setting, but now I have the error ```MSB3191```. And when I call ```settings.isWritable();``` I think it returns me ```true``` because he don't take the permission in consideration.

Comment: Are you using VS or Qt Creator? That error is an indication that the compiler has no authorization to write the output file (permissions or invalid path). Check your destination path. A quick googling about it have returned me several different solutions, I think it will be quicker if you check them out.

Comment: BTW, if you disable it again can you compile? otherwise the problem is in another change... again, check the destination path/name for invalid characters or invalid paths (`c:\program files...`, `c:\users\c:\users...`).

Comment: Yes, if I disable it I can compile again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144580/discussion-between-cbuchart-and-thibaut-b).

Comment: It was effectivelly a permission issue, after ```sync()```,  ```status()``` returns ```QSettings::AccessError``` which means "*An access error occurred (e.g. trying to write to a read-only file).*" even if the file is open with ```QIODevice::ReadWrite```.

Comment: Glad to know you've solved the issue! I'll take note of it too, thanks!